# Removing last row and extending dataframe prints dataframe with the removed row

Tags: dataframe, rust, rust-polars

Why is it when I try and remove the last row a dataframe and insert a new row, it still shows the previous row I tried to remove with the new row?

```rust
if self.dataframes.minute()["broker_time"].utf8().unwrap().into_iter().any(|i| i.unwrap() == candle.broker_time()) {
  let size = self.dataframes.get_timeframe(&ETimeFrames::Minute).shape();
   self.dataframes.minute = self.dataframes.minute.head(Some(size.0 - 1));
}
println!("{:#?}", self.dataframes.minute); // prints self.dataframes.minute with the last row removed

let df = df!(..).unwrap() // create df with new data with same columns as original data
self.dataframes.minute.extend(&df).unwrap();
println!("{:#?}", self.dataframes.minute); // shows the row as if it wasn't removed and extends the new df
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using [vstack_mut](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/polars/frame/struct.DataFrame.html#method.vstack_mut) instead of [extend](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/polars/frame/struct.DataFrame.html#method.extend)

`vstack_mut` works instead of `extend` because as per the documentation:

`vstack` adds the chunks from other to the chunks of this DataFrame

Whereas `extend` appends the data from other to the underlying memory locations and thus may cause a reallocation.

More info can be  found in the docs linked above.

Comment: Please can you explain why you believe this is the correct answer?

Comment: @Fletch I updated the explanation.